# Inheritance in Django

Tags: django

```
class OldComputer:
    transistors = models.IntegerField(null=False)

class SuperComputer(OldComputer):
    objects = models.Manager()
    transistorCount = models.IntegerField(default=500)
```

```
in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I get the above error when calling `SuperComputer.objects.create()`
Why is this?
When inheriting from a Parent class, do i have to provide values for the inherited fields?

Comment: Shouldn't `OldComputer` inherit from `models.Model`?

Comment: I guess this should be `obj = super().save(**kwargs)`